# Keeping part of string if "MEXICO" appears as substring after other characters

Tags: postgresql-9.3, regexp-replace

I am struggling with the following problem in PostgreSQL: I have a huge list of addresses from Mexico.

I want to delete the word MEXICO whenever it appears in a city name and does not refer to the city MEXICO CITY, but to the country as a whole, e.g. "CITY NAME, MEXICO".

```
SELECT city_, zip_code, 
       regexp_replace(city_, '\s+\mMEXICO\M', '', 'g') 
from addresses
```

does not work as entries for MEXICO CITY will be deleted.
Typically, the country MEXICO appears after some other characters, and a whitespace.

```
SELECT city_, zip_code, 
       regexp_replace(city_, '[A-Z]+\s+\mMEXICO\M', '', 'g') 
from addresses
```

does not work, too, because the whole string will be dropped.

Hence, I am looking for an option in order to replace `[A-Z]+\s+\mMEXICO\M` with `[A-Z]+\s+`.

To complicate things, MEXICO CITY very often does not appear as MEXICO city, but as something like "MEXICO, Postal Code".

Therefore, I think the only way to identify the MEXICOs to be dropped is if there are some other characters before MEXICO.

Comment: `... where city_ NOT like '%mexico city%'` or the re equivalent

Comment: Unfortunately, many entries for "MEXICO CITY" does not show up as "MEXICO CITY", but as "MEXICO + Postal Code". I edited this in my initial post. In addition, I suspect that an additional WHERE will make the whole query inefficient.